# jquery pass value from main window to popup window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web

i want to pass value from my main window to the popup window i am  tryin to use jquery 
i already using list of item to show them as a grid view i want when the user click on detail button its show to him popup window   i want to pass price value to the popup window any ware in the modal body

```
  while ( $sql=mysqli_fetch_assoc($posts)){
        echo' <div class="item  col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="thumbnail" >
            <img class="group lis t-group-image" style="height: 221px;
width: 353px; padding: 2px;
" src="../1'.$sql['img'].'" />
            <div class="caption" style="height: 105px;">
                <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                    '.$sql['name'].'</h4>
                <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
                    '.$sql['details'].' </p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                        <p id="price1" class="lead">سعر المنتج:'.$sql['price'].'</p></div>

                </div>
            </div>

           <button id="btn1">Show Text</button>
           <button data-toggle="modal" data-id="price1"  id="ww" class="btn btn-primary">details </button>
           <!--button data-toggle="modal" href="#shortModal"  id="ww" class="btn btn-primary">مشاهدة التفاصيل</button-->


            <!--button type="button" onclick="on_create_form_clicked();" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product_view"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Quick View</button -->
        </div>
    </div>';
    }
    ?>
```

and here is the popup modal

```
<div id="shortModal" class="modal modal-wide fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body…</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

i want to pass the value to popup window to show details  so any help ?

Comment: You question is a bit unclear about what values you want to be parsed, and where it should be placed

Comment: where is the javascript?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i want to pass price value to the popup window any ware in the modal body

Comment: For jquery model popup no need to pass any parameter.Use the same php `$sql['price']` to get the price value

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through using Jquery
Add Id to title of Modal or wherever you want the value to be displayed

```
<h4 class="modal-title" id ="ans">Modal title</h4>
```

Add data-id for the data to be passed to the modal

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-id="yourdata"  id="ww" class="btn btn-primary">details </button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#ww").click(function () {
        $('#ans').val($(this).data('id'));
        $('#shortModal').modal('show');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a click event and get the values of the price by using `$("#price1").text()`

```
$('#ww').click(function() {
  $("#shortModal .modal-body").text($("#price1").text())
})
```

```js
$('#ww').click(function() {
  $("#shortModal .modal-body").text($("#price1").text())
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img class="group lis t-group-image" style="height: 221px;
width: 353px; padding: 2px;
" src="../1'.$sql['img'].'" />
  <div class="caption" style="height: 105px;">
    <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
      '.$sql['name'].'</h4>
    <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
      '.$sql['details'].' </p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <p id="price1" class="lead">prdoudct price : 2000</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="btn1">Show Text</button>
  <button data-toggle="modal" href="#shortModal" id="ww" class="btn btn-primary">details </button>



</div>

<div id="shortModal" class="modal modal-wide fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Comment: not work bro because i have a more than thumbnail in my web page

Comment: @Onecode Where did you say that you had more than one in your original post?

Comment: Add some more of your code so we can help you, also why do you mark an answer when you say the answer is not working. You give the wrong impression to other people that might have the same problem.

Comment: You marked one of the answers as the correct answer to your problem 32 min ago

Comment: i corect both >

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you can add `modal` in your loop and set dynamic modal 
id.

Try below code.

**HTML/PHP**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<?php
$array=array();
$array[0]['name'] = 'Sony Pendrive';
$array[0]['details'] = '16 GB 2.0';
$array[0]['price'] = '120';
$array[1]['name'] = 'PNY Pendrive';
$array[1]['details'] = '32 GB 2.0';
$array[1]['price'] = '220';
foreach($array as $k=>$values){
?>
    <div class="thumbnail" >
        <div class="caption" style="height: 105px;">
            <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                <?php echo $values['name']; ?>
            </h4>
            <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
                <?php echo $values['details']; ?>
            </p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                <p id="price1" class="lead">prdoudct price : <?php echo $values['price']; ?></p></div>
            </div>
        </div>

       <button id="btn1">Show Text</button>
       <button data-toggle="modal" href="#shortModal_<?php echo $k; ?>"  id="ww" class="btn btn-primary">details </button>
    </div>

    <div id="shortModal_<?php echo $k; ?>" class="modal modal-wide fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>
                        Name : <?php echo $values['name']; ?> <br />
                        Details : <?php echo $values['details']; ?> <br />
                        Price : <?php echo $values['price']; ?> <br />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

> In this code create Array and set dynamic model id for open specific model.

Comment: this will work if i have only one thumbnail class but what if i have for example more than 5 thumbnail ? the value of thumbnail 5 i will  show for all the thumbnail